# Can't use the json_v2 plugin of telegraf to extract the correct fields in my json

Tags: json, parsing, telegraf, jsonplugin

I'm out of ideas out to parse my simple Json data in Telegraf

I have this file

```
{
  "inc_code": "I1",
  "sensors": [
    {
      "n": 1,
      "aX": 12
    },
    {
      "n": 2,
      "aX": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

and my expected output in telegraf is

```
I1, n=1 aX=12
I1, n=2 aX=50
```

How should be the telegraf.com file?

I've tried

```
  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
     measurement_name_path = "inc_code"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.tag]]
          path = "sensors.#.n"
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
          path = "sensors.#.aX"
          type = "float"
```

which results in

```
I1,n=1 aX=12 1690565287967408422
I1,n=1 aX=50 1690565287967408422
I1,n=2 aX=12 1690565287967408422
I1,n=2 aX=50 1690565287967408422
```

Where is a duplication of the values. I don't need lines two and three!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. I came across this PR which was merged into version 1.28.2: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/14008

I tried upgrading telegraf and it hasn't fixed my problem, but maybe it will fix yours.